# Rfid 14443a standards

Tags: rfid

I need 14443a rfid standarts commands. like read and write. I find the read command which is 0109000304A0010000. I need write command for this.  thanks best regards.

Comment: See: http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/667/t/161386.aspx?pi239031352=2

Comment: You should probably check out http://electronics.stackexchange.com for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The [ISO/IEC 14443A spec part 4](http://www.waazaa.org/download/fcd-14443-4.pdf) contains all the data you should need to deal with such RFID devices.

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=0109000304A0010000) on the read command produces a wealth of information from people who have successfully build projects using it.

Comment: Is there a reason you've un-accepted my answer? Did I miss something?